# Django Form DecimalField Min value validation error

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, validationerror

I am working on Django form with a Decimal Field, in the form class:
I　have :
field1= forms.DecimalField(required=False, max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, max_value=1.0, min_value=0.1)

when I　set the value of the field to 0.1 from UI and save, I got error:
Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne2cf.png)

I've tried many ways to fix it but didn't work.

Is it a Django problem?
What should I do to fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.